# WPF Can I alter the sensitivity for mouse events on a Path shape

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF Path inside a Canvas and I wish to detect mouse events on it. I know how to do this but my question is: can I set any 'nearness' value/prop that will cause an event to fire if the mouse is close to (not just on) the Path's underlying shape?

Can't see anything in MS specs for Path.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this "natively", but you could get by with a simple solution of making the canvas's stroke larger, and transparent--so it is bigger, but does not appear like that to the user.

Comment: Presume you mean Path's Stroke not Canvas. This wouldn't work because I want the Path to be visible (unless I'm missing something?). Thanks for the response.

Comment: Could always make a clone of the Path and set it's Stroke to transparent and stroke larger, then overlay it on the Path

Comment: My apologies, I meant to type path. The path's stroke would be what is placed on the outside of the already created path, so your path would be still visible, assuming your path's background is not transparent as well.

Comment: override  onMouseMove of canvas and check Position.X and Position.Y +10/-10 by using VisualTreeHelper.HitTest , for  example : if Position.X+10 is on a path then fire an event you want.